# Different interface layout for different level users in yii

Tags: php, user-interface, layout, yii, module

I'm new to Yii. I'm developing a system with YII framework in PHP. How can I have a different layout for different module? I want the module A to have interface A, module B with interface B. But what I have know is that the interface login is the same for all module login. Can someone give me a light?

Update:

I found one way which is to include the:

```
$this->layout = $layout;
```

on the action function inside the controller before rendering the page. However, I found that it's not that efficient as on every action I need to repeat the line. Is there a way where we can do the setting on the config/main.php page? probably on this part:

```
'modules'=>array(
     'gii'=>array(
        'class'=>'system.gii.GiiModule',
        'password'=>'123',
        'generatorPaths' => array('bootstrap.gii'),
     ),          

     'admin',
     'consultant',
     'client',
),
```

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advanced".

Answer (score 1):

You can set variables for your module in your `config` like this:

```
'modules'=>array(
     'gii'=>array(
        'class'=>'system.gii.GiiModule',
        'password'=>'123',
        'generatorPaths' => array('bootstrap.gii'),
     ),          

     'admin' => array(
        'layout' => 'your_layout' //The layout for this module
     ),
     'consultant',
     'client',
),
```

This way you can implement a default layout for every single module. Without having to add `controller` methods or variables.

For more info see the docs: [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CWebModule#layout-detail) and [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/basics.module)

Comment: Hi, I tried the way that you mentioned, but how should I write the code so that I can connect to the controller that I have? ex. the module is admin. Inside the admin->components->Controller.php

Comment: From my first "here" link: "$layout. The layout that is shared by the controllers inside this module. If a controller has explicitly declared its own layout, this property will be ignored. If this is null (default), the application's layout or the parent module's layout (if available) will be used. If this is false, then no layout will be used." This is the layout variable you are setting in your `config`. So try setting it to `false`, if it shows no layout it works and `Yii` probably can't find your specific layout.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
class YourController extends Controller {

    public $layout = 'your_layout';

}
```